# Regular Expression for Fckeditor

Tags: php, regex, fckeditor

I am having trouble with Fckeditor and a regular expression I am using to patch the problem.

Current problem: Relative URLs within the content (eg. images) results in 404 errors and red X's instead of images. Once the page renders on the front end of the site, the HTML links are valid from that relative directory. Within the admin though, that is not the case.

I wanted to automatically precede image calls with the full site URL to help avoid this. This is what I have, and it just is not working:

```
$html = preg_replace('/src="images\//', 'src="'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/images/', $pageDescription);
```

It doesn't seem to find anything based on the pattern; it just returns what I gave it.

Comment: Every time I see "FCKeditor" I put a 'U' in there!

Comment: It [works for me](http://codepad.org/xUPVASkY).